# Button with loop that iteratively updates slider in Manipulate

Tags: manipulate, dynamic, variable

I have the toy `Manipulate`.

```
Manipulate[
 Graphics[{Red, PointSize[0.05], Point[{a, -1}]}, Frame -> True, 
  ImageSize -> Small, PlotRange -> {{4, 6}, {-2, 0}}], 
 Style["Some parameters", Bold], 
 {{a, 5}, 4, 6, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
 Button["Shifts", a = RandomReal[{4, 6}]], 
 Button["Experiment", tmp = {}; Do[{a = RandomReal[{4, 6}];
    tmp = Append[tmp, a]; 
    Print[tmp]; 
    Pause[0.5]}, {5}], 
  Method -> "Queued"], TrackedSymbols :> {a}, 
 ControlPlacement -> Left, SynchronousUpdating -> True]
```

All I need is to make "Experiment" button to work as if I click "Shifts" button 5 times **in a run** (slider with `a` should update each cycle, 5 times). Now it stays unchanged during experiment and only undates in the end, during last iteration of the loop.

To keep `Do` is not important but I need something that would emulate `Append` cycle.

PS. Why do I need that? I want to show students one effect on the market and it is important that they see in real time that `a` changes as `a` is the reason of that shifts (I could click it myself but it seems a bit unprofessional and boaring :).

Comment: `Button["Experiment", Do[{a = RandomReal[{4, 6}]; Pause[0.5]}, {5}], 
 Method -> "Queued"]` You forgot the curly braces around the 5

Comment: @Dr.belisarius. The `{ }` aren't required in versions sufficiently later than yours, which I believe to be V9.

Comment: @Dr.belisarius, I'm on version 10.3, but I've made a change that you suggested and updated post. Any further ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`DynamicWrapper`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DynamicWrapper.html) can help.

```
Manipulate[
 DynamicWrapper[            (* allows for the iteration step below to be updated *)
  Dynamic@                  (* this Dynamic causes Graphics to depend on its variables *)
   Graphics[{Red, PointSize[0.05], Point[{a, -1}]}, Frame -> True, 
    ImageSize -> Small, PlotRange -> {{4, 6}, {-2, 0}}],
  Refresh[                  (* iteration step *)
   If[iterate > 0,             (* update  a *)
    iterate--;
    a = RandomReal[{4, 6}]
    ],
   UpdateInterval -> 0.5,      (* update every half second... *)
   TrackedSymbols -> {}]       (* and NOT when  iterate  or  a  is changed *)
  ],
 Style["Some parameters", Bold],
 {{a, 5}, 4, 6, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{iterate, 0}, ControlType -> None},
 Button["Shifts", a = RandomReal[{4, 6}]],
 Button["Experiment",
  iterate = 5,                           (* set number of iterations *)
  Enabled -> Dynamic[iterate == 0]],     (* turn off button while experimenting *)
 TrackedSymbols :> {},                   (* so the whole is not reevaluated; see note *)
 ControlPlacement -> Left, SynchronousUpdating -> True]
```

The iteration step is run every 0.5 seconds, but `a` is updated only when `iterate > 0`.  Between experiments, it is basically a no-op.  If you use another variable `wait`, use `UpdateInterval -> wait`, and toggle `wait` between `0.5` and `Infinity`, the continual updating may be stopped between experiments.  The 0.5 sec. updating does not affect the performance of this specific demonstration.  I mention this alternative in case it is a problem in other use-cases.

*Note: Why `TrackedSymbols :> {}` --* 
The trick used here is to have to separate (or parallel) pieces of code in the body of `Manipulate`.  These are created by

```
DynamicWrapper[Dynamic[code1], code2]
```

The first argument of `DynamicWrapper` is not dynamically updated by default*, so `code1` needs to be wrapped in `Dynamic` for it to respond independently to changes in `a`.  We do not want the whole `DynamicWrapper` to be re-evaluated whenever `a` or `iterate` changes, because it would cause the iteration step to be evaluated again, too.  Thus `a` and `iterate` would be updated, without the 0.5 second wait, and their change would trigger another immediate update, and so on.  In short, the experiment would be short, with the five iterations happening as fast as possible.

*The documentation is a little confusing about this: "When used to display `e` in a notebook, `DynamicWrapper[e,expr]` is effectively equivalent to `Dynamic[expr;Refresh[e,None]]`."  But this is not literally true, at least in all cases (including this one), as can be easily checked.

Comment: I would never find that sort of solution: that is impressive!

Comment: @garej Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

#### Update

OK, I think I understand now. It can sort of be done by faking the manipulator current value label. The slider still won't move in real time, but the value displayed on the right will update as it should.

I don't know how to get the slider to update as you want. The slider movement seems to be controlled too deeply for me get at. Maybe abandoning `Manipulate` and going down to the `DynamicModule` level might work, but I don't have time to try that at the moment.

```
Manipulate[
  Graphics[{Red, PointSize[0.05], Point[{a, -1}]},
    Frame -> True, ImageSize -> Small, PlotRange -> {{4, 6}, {-2, 0}}],
  Style["Some parameters", 12, Bold],
  Dynamic @ Row[{Control[{{a, 5}, 4, 6}], "  ", a}],
  Button["Shifts", a = RandomReal[{4, 6}]],
  Button["Experiment",
    Do[a = RandomReal[{4, 6}]; Pause[.5], 5],
    Method -> "Queued"],
  ControlPlacement -> Left,
  SynchronousUpdating -> True]
```

[image: demo]

Comment: I've noticed your edit. Let me try again to explain ;) If we click `Shifts`, the point shifts and slider `a` value shifts. Ok? If we click `Experiment`, the point shifts 5 times _but_ slider `a` value shifts _only once_ - during last iteration. Is there a way to make slider `a` value to shift 5 times - each time when the point shifts? Or there is not allowed in Manipulate?